# How can I check if a list contains any value from another list?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Using [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/), I can check if a list contains a single item:

```
_.contains([1, 2, 3], 3);
```

Now I want to extend this to check if a list contains any item from another list:

```
_.contains([1, 2, 3], [4, 1]);
```

This is what I've got, but is there a neater way?

```
var isInList = _.some(_.map([1, 2, 3], function(d){ return _.contains([4, 1], d); }));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`_.intersection`](http://underscorejs.org/#intersection) function, like this

```
var isInList = _.intersection([1, 2, 3], [4, 1]).length !== 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want [`_.intersection`](http://underscorejs.org/#intersection).  This returns the set of elements that appear in both arrays.  For example,

```
_.intersection([1, 2, 3], [4, 1])
> [1]
```

To turn it into the boolean you're looking for, just check if the returned array is empty.